# using string to set default selection of drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list that comes from a sqldatasource that is presented in alphabetical order. Because of this, the lists index numbers do not line up at all with the primary keys within the SQL table. I need to be able to set the drop down list's selection on page load based on primary key information I have.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="catagoryDropDown" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"
     DataTextField="Catagory" DataValueField="PK_SupportCatagory" CssClass="dropDownList">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$     
     ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT [PK_SupportCatagory], [Catagory] FROM [SupportCatagory] ORDER BY CASE  
     WHEN [PK_SupportCatagory] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, [Catagory]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My thought is to get the string by querying the database using that to set the drop down list appropriately.

```
catagoryDropDown.SelectedValue = "Sick Leave";
```

The above does not work. How would I accomplish this? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garrison Neely's answer did not quite work but it got me on the right track. This ultimatly worked:

```
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in catagoryDropDown.Items)
            {
                if (item.ToString().Equals("Sick Leave"))
                {
                    catagoryDropDown.SelectedIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
```

Comment: Always awesome to answer your own question!

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectedIndex = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < catagoryDropDown.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if(catagoryDropDown.Items[i].Text.ToLower() == "sick leave")
    {
        selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

if(selectedIndex > -1)
{
    catagoryDropDown.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
}
```

Added the .ToLower() because it makes things easier when strings don't have case worries.

Comment: What is `item` in this context?

Comment: hah, forgot to change that part from my initial implementation in a foreach.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
catagoryDropDown.SelectedValue = catagoryDropDown.Items.FindByText("Sick Leave").Value;
```

Comment: Getting a NullReferenceException

Comment: Which part is `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this One, I am pretty sure it will work:

```
ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.Items.IndexOf(ddl.Items.FindByText(Convert.ToString(Any Value)));
```

> Make sure the value exist in the datasource (to which the ddl is bound) before.

Comment: for setting the index of ddl dynamically with respect to any list item value coming from datasource (to which ddl is bound) its the simplest way.